# PHP won't get ID on the BDD

Tags: php, sql

and thanks to read.

So i'm using the MVC model and i'm trying to get the AUTO_INCREMENT ID in a MySQL BDD from the **e-mail** that the user enter when he signed up.

There is the function in APIManager.php :

```
public function getIDBDUser($lemail){

    $req = "SELECT ID_USER FROM user WHERE mail =':lemail'";
    $stmt = $this->getBdd()->prepare($req); 
    $stmt->bindParam(':lemail', $lemail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    //$stmt->closeCursor();
    $id = $stmt->fetchAll();
    var_dump($id);
    return $id;
    
}
```

and in APIController.php

```
public function getIDUser($lemail){
    $id = $this->apimanager->getIDBDUser($lemail);
    return $id;
}
```

and in the front page.php

```
if (isset($_POST['deleteUser'])) {
    $lid = $apicontrol->getIDUser($_SESSION['nomUser']);
    var_dump($lid);
    // $apicontrol->deleteUser($lid);
    // header("Location : index.html");
}
```

The Model.php is working fine, and i tried different SQL Request, but that is not the problem. Names of tables etc, are correct

Thanks for your help ! :)

Comment: Are you sure ```$_SESSION['nomUser']``` contains a correct email? You should ```var_dump()``` that too

Answer (score 1):

With adding the single quotes you actually double them, so simply make

```
 $req = "SELECT ID_USER FROM user WHERE mail = :lemail";
```

Comment: Wo it was the problem ! Thanks you very much you're a chief !

Comment: @Pikate If an answer worked for you and solved your problem, [don't forget to accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)